# Write a recursive function to map data for all levels

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, callback

I have a data mapper function which takes json with four levels of data and then map then to a different format

Input JSON format:

```
[{
    "InventoryLevel2Id": "1234",
    "InventoryLevel2Information": "Test Data",
    "InventoryLevel2Name": "Test Data",
    "InventoryLevel3s": [
        {
            "InventoryLevel3Id": "5678",
            "InventoryLevel3Name": "Inner data at 1",
            "InventoryLevel3Information": "Inner info at 1",
            "InventoryLevel4s": [
                {
                    "InventoryLevel4Id": "9101112",
                    "InventoryLevel4Name": "Inner data at 2",
                    "InventoryLevel4Information": "Inner info at 2",
                    "InventoryLevel5s": [
                        {
                            "InventoryLevel5Id": "131415",
                            "InventoryLevel5Name": "Inner data at 3",
                            "InventoryLevel5Information": "Inner info at 3",
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Ouput JSON format:

```
[{
    label1: 'TestData',
    label2: "Test data",
    uniquieId: "1234",
    innerState: {
        data : {
            label1: 'Inner data at 1',
            label2: "Inner info at 1",
            uniquieId: "5678",
            innerState: {
                data: {
                    label1: 'Inner data at 2',
                    label2: "Inner info at 2",
                    uniquieId: "9101112",
                    innerState: {
                        data: {
                            label1: 'Inner data at 3',
                            label2: "Inner info at 4",
                            uniquieId: "131415",
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

For this , I wrote this mapper function. This works fine , but I have to call the mapper again and again. To optimize , I am thinking of creating a reccursive function which will call it self , till mapping for all levels are done .

```
const dataMapperFunc = (
    inputData
  ) => {
    const mappedData = inputData?.map((a) => ({
      label1: a.InventoryLevel2Name,
      label2: a.InventoryLevel2Information,
      uniquieId: a.InventoryLevel2Id,
      innerState: {
        data: a.InventoryLevel3s?.map((b) => ({
          label1: b.InventoryLevel3Name,
          label2: b.InventoryLevel3Information,
          uniquieId: b.InventoryLevel3Id,
          innerState: {
            data: b.InventoryLevel4s?.map(
              (c) => ({
                label1: c.InventoryLevel4Name,
                label2: c.InventoryLevel4Information,
                uniquieId: c.InventoryLevel4Id,
                innerState: {
                  data: c.InventoryLevel5s?.map(
                    (d) => ({
                      label1: d.InventoryLevel5Name,
                      label2:
                        d.InventoryLevel5Information,
                      uniquieId: d.InventoryLevel5Id,
                    })
                  ),
                },
              })
            ),
          },
        })),
      },
    }));
    return mappedData;
  };
```

This is my attempt on mapper function which stopes at InventoryLevel3s and not complete. I am missing few steps and it can be done better.

```
const dataMapperFuncTryReccursive = (inputData ) => {
  const mappedData = inputData?.map((a) =>
    mapper(
      a,
      "InventoryLevel2Name",
      "InventoryLevel2Information",
      "InventoryLevel3Id",
      "InventoryLevel3s"
    )
  );
  return mappedData;
};

const mapper = (entity, field1, field2, uniquieId, childEntityName) => {
  if (entity) {
    return {
      label1: entity[field1],
      label2: entity[field2],
      uniquieId: entity[uniquieId],
      concurrencyId: entity.concurrencyId,
      innerState: {
        data: entity[childEntityName]?.map((innerData) =>
          mapper(
            innerData,
            "InventoryLevel3Name",
            "InventoryLevel3Information",
            "InventoryLevel3Id",
            "InventoryLevel4s"
          )
        ),
      },
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: Why do you have the extra level of nesting with the `data` element inside `innerState`? it seems unnecessary since it is the only one.

Comment: Can there be multiple values at each level? The sample data only has one.

Comment: @Nick, Yes, there can be multiple values at each level. Each level is an array. And , agree, we wont need data inside inner state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive function that should give you the results you want. It extracts the current level number by replacing all non-numeric values from the first key of the input object, then uses that to find the appropriate properties to copy to the output:

```js
const data = [{
  "InventoryLevel2Id": "1234",
  "InventoryLevel2Information": "Test Data",
  "InventoryLevel2Name": "Test Data",
  "InventoryLevel3s": [{
    "InventoryLevel3Id": "5678",
    "InventoryLevel3Name": "Inner data at 1",
    "InventoryLevel3Information": "Inner info at 1",
    "InventoryLevel4s": [{
      "InventoryLevel4Id": "9101112",
      "InventoryLevel4Name": "Inner data at 2",
      "InventoryLevel4Information": "Inner info at 2",
      "InventoryLevel5s": [{
        "InventoryLevel5Id": "131415",
        "InventoryLevel5Name": "Inner data at 3",
        "InventoryLevel5Information": "Inner info at 3",
      }],
    }]
  }]
}]

const mapdata = (data) => {
  let level = +Object.keys(data)[0].replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
  const obj = {
    label1: data['InventoryLevel' + level + 'Name'],
    label2: data['InventoryLevel' + level + 'Information'],
    uniqueId: data['InventoryLevel' + level + 'Id']
  };
  level++;
  if (data.hasOwnProperty('InventoryLevel' + level + 's')) {
    obj.innerState = data['InventoryLevel' + level + 's'].map(mapdata);
  }
  return obj;
}

out = data.map(mapdata);
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it. Just match with a wildcard on the number and you can do it with a small recursive function.

```js
const data = [{
    "InventoryLevel2Id": "1234",
    "InventoryLevel2Information": "Test Data",
    "InventoryLevel2Name": "Test Data",
    "InventoryLevel3s": [
        {
            "InventoryLevel3Id": "5678",
            "InventoryLevel3Name": "Inner data at 1",
            "InventoryLevel3Information": "Inner info at 1",
            "InventoryLevel4s": [
                {
                    "InventoryLevel4Id": "9101112",
                    "InventoryLevel4Name": "Inner data at 2",
                    "InventoryLevel4Information": "Inner info at 2",
                    "InventoryLevel5s": [
                        {
                            "InventoryLevel5Id": "131415",
                            "InventoryLevel5Name": "Inner data at 3",
                            "InventoryLevel5Information": "Inner info at 3",
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]

const mapRecursive = (inputData) =>
    inputData.map(item =>
        Object.keys(item).reduce((obj, key) => {
            if (key.match("InventoryLevel.Id")) return { ...obj, uniquieId: item[key] };
            if (key.match("InventoryLevel.Name")) return { ...obj, label1: item[key] };
            if (key.match("InventoryLevel.Information")) return { ...obj, label2: item[key] };
            if (key.match("InventoryLevel.s")) return { ...obj, innerState: { data: mapRecursive(item[key]) } };
        }, {})
    );

console.log(mapRecursive(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be an advantage in making this more declarative through the use of a helper function.

This version uses a list of mappings between regular expressions and new keys, with a boolean property to note where to recur.  Using the `transform` helper function, the code for this problem looks like this:

```js
const mapData = transform ([
  {oldKey: /^InventoryLevel\d+Id$/, newKey: 'uniqueId'},
  {oldKey: /^InventoryLevel\d+Name$/, newKey:'label1'},
  {oldKey: /^InventoryLevel\d+Information$/, newKey: 'label2'},
  {oldKey: /^InventoryLevel\d+s$/, newKey: 'innerState', recur: true},
])
```

Of course the `transform` function is now useful for other similar problems.  But it's not just that reusability that's important here.  More important is the breakdown of the problem into the node conversion and recursion on one hand, and the details of the specific node transformations on the other.  It should be very clear where to add additional nodes.

Here is an implementation of `transform`:

```js
const transform = (config) => (objs) =>
  objs .map ((obj) =>
    Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (([k, v]) => { 
      const {newKey = '', recur = false} = config .find (({oldKey}) => oldKey .test (k))
      return newKey
        ? [[newKey, recur ? transform (config) (v) : v]]
        : []       
    }))
  )

const mapData = transform ([
  {oldKey: /^InventoryLevel\d+Id$/, newKey: 'uniqueId'},
  {oldKey: /^InventoryLevel\d+Name$/, newKey:'label1'},
  {oldKey: /^InventoryLevel\d+Information$/, newKey: 'label2'},
  {oldKey: /^InventoryLevel\d+s$/, newKey: 'innerState', recur: true},
])

const input = [{InventoryLevel2Id: "1234", InventoryLevel2Information: "Test Data", InventoryLevel2Name: "Test Data", InventoryLevel3s: [{InventoryLevel3Id: "5678", InventoryLevel3Name: "Inner data at 1", InventoryLevel3Information: "Inner info at 1", InventoryLevel4s: [{InventoryLevel4Id: "9101112", InventoryLevel4Name: "Inner data at 2", InventoryLevel4Information: "Inner info at 2", InventoryLevel5s: [{InventoryLevel5Id: "131415", InventoryLevel5Name: "Inner data at 3", InventoryLevel5Information: "Inner info at 3"}]}]}]}]

console .log (mapData (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that the output matches the format in Nick's answer.  The requested format does not match the comment that, "Yes, there can be multiple values at each level. Each level is an array," even after removing the `data` node.  The point is that the `innerState` elements are arrays and not plain objects.

There is plenty of room to make `transform` more generic.  But there's a tradeoff.  The more generic we make this, the more we will have to do in the configuration.  For comparison, my first version looked more like this:

```js
const transform = (config) => (objs) =>
  objs .map ((obj) => 
    Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (([k, v]) => 
      (config .find (({test}) => test(k)) || {result: () => []}) .result (v)
    ))
  )

const mapData = transform ([
  {test: (k) => /^InventoryLevel\d+Id$/.test(k), result: (v) => [['uniqueId', v]]},
  {test: (k) => /^InventoryLevel\d+Name$/.test(k), result: (v) => [['label1', v]]},
  {test: (k) => /^InventoryLevel\d+Information$/.test(k), result: (v) => [['label2', v]]},
  {test: (k) => /^InventoryLevel\d+s$/.test(k), result: (v) => [['innerState', mapData (v)]]},
])
```

Note that `transform` is simply more powerful.  It allows for arbitrary test functions in the configuration, paired with output functions that can create whatever nodes are necessary.  For instance, it could turn one input node into three output ones.  But note how much more complex the configuration array is.  Instead of `{oldKey: /^InventoryLevel\d+Id$/`, we need `test: (k) => /^InventoryLevel\d+Id$/.test(k)`.  And instead of `result: (v) => [['uniqueId', v]]`, we have `result: (v) => [['uniqueId', v]]`.  Moreover, we have to explicitly call the recursion, instead of noting it with a boolean property.

We could go the other direction too, if we chose, making the configuration still simpler at the expense of a slightly more complex `transform` function.  Perhaps this would be nicer:

```js
const transform = (config) => (objs) =>
  objs .map ((obj) =>
    Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (([k, v]) => { 
      const {newKey, recur} = config .find (
        ({oldKey}) => new RegExp (`^${oldKey .replace ('#', '\\d+')}$`) .test (k)
      )
      return newKey
        ? [[newKey, recur ? transform (config) (v) : v]]
        : []       
    }))
  )

const mapData = transform ([
  {oldKey: 'InventoryLevel#Id', newKey: 'uniqueId'},
  {oldKey: 'InventoryLevel#Name', newKey:'label1'},
  {oldKey: 'InventoryLevel#Information', newKey: 'label2'},
  {oldKey: 'InventoryLevel#s', newKey: 'innerState', recur: true},
])
```

Now our configuration needs know nothing about regular expressions, and we can simply use a `#` wildcard for a collection of digits.  This makes `transform` even less generic and less powerful, but it does simplify the configuration.  If you're certain you'll never reuse `transform`, this is probably a good choice.